# How to sync a local file with the server copy

Tags: clearcase-ucm, cleartool

Is there a way to sync a file from local repository with the corresponding clearcase server copy?

Can this be done by executing any command from cleartool?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That makes sense in a snapshot view.
In such a view, you can use [`cleartool update`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm):

```
 cleartool update -force -rename aFile
```

That would replace any local modification by the version currently selected by the config spec of the UCM view you are in.

However, that config spec might not reflect the configuration of the stream if references.
Someone else can have changed the configuration of the stream (rebase), and your view would still reflect the old baselines.

So to be sure to get the *right* version (ie the one referenced by the stream), you can first reset the config spec of your view to the configuration of the stream.

```
cd /path/to/your/view
cleartool setcs -stream
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC for such a quick response :) I will try this one and see how it works.